# Passing control's ID to javascript via ScriptControlDescriptor

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I create a control in CreateChildControls():

```
HtmlGenericControl mycontrol= HtmlGenericControl("li");
mycontrol.ID = "controlID";

controlId = mycontrol.ID;


protected virtual IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors()
{
        ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor("Project.TEditor", this.ClientID);                   

        descriptor.AddProperty("controlId", controlId);           
        return new ScriptDescriptor[] { descriptor };          
}
```

Then in javascript i try to find this control using the ID property:

```
 alert($get(this.get_controlId()));
```

I get null because the actual control ID has a prefix that was added by asp.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try **mycontrol.ClientID** instead of **mycontrol.ID** for client side reference :

```
// At CreateChildControls : 
HtmlGenericControl mycontrol= HtmlGenericControl("li");
mycontrol.ID = "controlID";

// After you add your control to page (Page.Controls.Add(myControl)) : 
controlId = mycontrol.ClientID;

protected virtual IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors()
{
        ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor("Project.TEditor", this.ClientID);                   

        descriptor.AddProperty("controlId", controlId);           
        return new ScriptDescriptor[] { descriptor };          
}
```

Comment: IS it possible to get ID before the control is added to the page? 
(because I add controls to the page in "reverse order": child->parent->it's parent->... so this control is added to the page after I already don't have the reference to the control)